# Как указать чтобы выбирался целый файл при конфликте?

Tags: ubuntu, git, gitkraken

Когда открываю окно сравнение файла, то там нет кнопки использовать весь правый или левый файл. То есть заменить один другим. Вместо этого файлы скрещиваются.

Можно ли как то в gitKraken это указать, либо как использовать другую утилиту в ubuntu где такая функция есть?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Поставьте и настройте `emacs`. В нём весьма навороченный модуль работы с Git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> либо как использовать другую утилиту в ubuntu где такая функция есть?

это, конечно, очень удивительно, но такая «утилита» есть, и называется она «программа *git*».

---

пример.

я внёс в `file` строку `user 1`, а второй пользователь — строку `user 2` (причём раньше меня и успел отправить изменение в общее хранлище).

после команды *pull* я получаю конфилкт:

```
$ git pull
...
Auto-merging file
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in file
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.

$ cat file 
<<<<<<< HEAD
user 1
=======
user 2
>>>>>>> efe04bd3df8d5add3f91c9a3b369f9b532124ecc
```

с помощью команды [*checkout*](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) я могу привести `file` к «своему» виду:

```
$ git checkout HEAD -- file
$ cat file
user 1
```

а могу к «чужому»:

```
$ git checkout efe04bd -- file
$ cat file
user 2
```

после чего завершить слияние:

```
$ git commit -a
```

Comment: Хочется через gui интерфейс аналогичный tortoise git. Там очень удобно было в 1 клик это сделать и не париться.